# Infer my object interface to type "object"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript. I'm using a component from a library that was built in TypeScript. I want to pass my own function to this component, which receives it as props:

```
import React from "react";
import ForceGraph from "react-force-graph-3d";
import { IProps } from "./interfaces";

export const Graph: React.FC<IProps> = ({ graph, onNodeClick }) => (
  <ForceGraph
    graphData={graph}
    nodeId="publicKey"
    nodeVisibility="visible"
    onNodeClick={onNodeClick}
    linkSource="node1"
    linkTarget="node2"
    nodeResolution={4}
    warmupTicks={25}
    cooldownTicks={0}
    rendererConfig={{
      antialias: false,
      powerPreference: "high-performance",
    }}
    onNodeHover={(d) => console.log(d)}
    enableNodeDrag={false}
  />
);
```

I'm trying to pass `onNodeClick` as props to it. I made the correct interface declaration in my component:

```
export interface IProps {
  graph: IGraph;
  onNodeClick?: (node: NodeObject, mouse: MouseEvent) => void;
}
```

`NodeObject` is the interface of the component I'm using, and it is:

```
type NodeObject = object & {
  id?: string | number;
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
  z?: number;
  vx?: number;
  vy?: number;
  vz?: number;
  fx?: number;
  fy?: number;
  fz?: number;
};
```

The `node` object receives all attributes from the `graph`, and my `node` interface is:

```
export interface INodesFunc {
  publicKey: string;
  alias: string;
  color: string;
  visible: boolean;
}
```

So `NodeObject` interface should contain my `node` attributes. Since the library is using the type `object`, how can I infer my `node` attributes to this `NodeObject`?

Right now I can't use my `node` attributes in my `handleNodeClick` function I'm passing to `onNodeClick`, because TypeScript complains that

> Property 'visible' does not exist on type 'NodeObject'

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

My `handleNodeClick` function is

```
const handleNodeClick = useCallback((node: INodesFunc) => {
  if (adjacencyList[node.publicKey].length <= 1) {
    node.visible = false; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
    setPrunedTree(getPrunedTree());
    return;
  }
  adjacencyList[node.publicKey].forEach((nodeId) => {
    nodesById[nodeId].visible = true;
  });
  setPrunedTree(getPrunedTree());
}, []);
```

And it's being passed as props to my `Graph` component:

```
<Graph
    graph={prunedTree}
    onNodeClick={(node: any) => handleNodeClick(node)}
  />
```

It works if I type `node: any`, but I want to do the right way

Comment: Where are you creating the `handleNodeClick` function?

Comment: I'm creating in a page and passing it as props to my component, then passing it as props to the component I'm using

Comment: Can you add that part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-glade-x0n2p?file=/src/App.tsx:0-498)

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ForceGraph from "react-force-graph-3d";
import type { NodeObject } from "react-force-graph-3d";

interface INodesFunc extends NodeObject {  // YOU'ARE EXTENGIN NodeObject TO MEET THE REQUIREMENTS
  publicKey?: string;  // MADE EVERYTHING EXTRA AS OPTIONAL
  alias?: string;
  color?: string;
  visible?: boolean;
}

export default function App() {
  const handleNodeClick = React.useCallback(
    (node: INodesFunc, event: MouseEvent) => {
      return;
    },
    []
  );

  return <ForceGraph onNodeClick={handleNodeClick} />;
}
```

The facts are:

- The `onNodeClick` prop from `<ForceGraph/>` is expecting something of the type `((node: NodeObject, event: MouseEvent) => void) | undefined`
- So you've got to pass something that meets those requirements. You can't add required properties to your function parameter `node` like you did because `<ForceGraph/>` will call that function following the contract parameters of `(node: NodeObject, event: MouseEvent)`.

If you add a required property named `visible` or whatever, it is going to show an error, because it needs to say to you something like: "the parameter that your function is expecting, I'm not gonna pass. Because the `NodeObject` that I'll pass, does not have that property".

That's why it works if you make your "extra" properties as optional. Because then `NodeObject` will meet those requirements, even without those properties.

Although I didn't fully understand why you need to do that, since those properties aren't coming through from the `onNodeClick` call/listener handler.